# Developer profile for a new ipad

Tags: iphone-developer-program

I have an iPad which has a developer profile enabled and I've been developing apps on it. I got the developer profile from a university program (from the iOS programming class that i took).

Now I would like to return the iPad I already own and would like to purchase a new one. I can't get a new developer profile from the university program anymore as the class has ended a long time ago.

Is there any solution to my situation other than jailbreaking/paying 99 bucks?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could to write to support of apple. They must to get you right answer. But you can pay 99 dollars, if that not so much for you.

Answer (score 0):

Because the profile is linked to your devices specific UDID that is unique to your current devices hardware even if you did copy the profile it would not work. There are some tutorials online to disable code signing by editing the backup file and restoring this worked for me in the past, but I do not know about the new firmwares. I could register your UDID and give you a new profile if you would like (for $5) you would not be able to put your apps on the AppStore though. Other than that your option is to jailbreak.